# Postgresql: database migrations refused because the database user is not table owner but is the database owner

Tags: postgresql, permissions

My migrations are failing on databases because of permissions.
Rephrase: My attempts to change a table design are failing with a permission error that I don't understand very well.

I did some refactoring of an application running on about 25 VMs, giving each instance a distinct user, and making the owner of the database this new user (via ansible). This has definitely worked. However, the tables remain owned by the original database owner, which is a superuser.
A script which changes table design (a django migration) is failing with a message that only the table owner can change the table design.
I thought that the database owner would be able to do this, but apparently not. Is it because the table owner is superuser, and somehow this trumps the database owner?

I'm using ansible so I'm hoping to find an answer in easy scope of ansible's capabilities. It seems there is not way to reassign ownership of just the tables. REASSIGN OWNED is not working because the current table owner has ownership of things which can't be moved from a superuser to a normal user.

I can fix this by enumerating each table to an ansible playbook, or perhaps by using ansible to run some SQL. But it feels like I am complicating the situation.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have 'migrations'.  This seem more like an ansible question than a PostgreSQL question,

Comment: my question is not about migrations: instead of "migration", read "attempt to change table design", my question is why the database owner can not change the table design. I am sorry this was not clear, but do not downvote my question because of that. The question is about Postgresql permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database owner can control who can create objects in the database with the `CREATE` privilege. The database owner does *not* gain any special privileges on objects created by other roles using that privilege, except as modified by any `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statements in force at the time of object creation. In other words, the database owner does not operate as a "superuser" inside its own database.*

To use `ALTER TABLE` you must be the table's owner; that is not a grantable privilege. The typical solution is to have the table owned by a role then grant the role to the users allowed to modify the table.

To change the owner of a table, the role executing `ALTER TABLE ... OWNER TO` (or `REASSIGN OWNED` for a mass change) must be a member of both the current owner('s role) and the target role. You may need to add the current owner to the target role temporarily. The fact the current owner is a superuser is irrelevant.

Obviously, if you have objects that depend on `SECURITY DEFINER` semantics then things get more complicated.

Depending on how limited your migration software is, you may have to create the roles with the `INHERIT` attribute so the users don't have to use `SET ROLE tableowner` to gain the ability to modify the table. It is recommended to require the use of `SET ROLE` to avoid accidents.

*: Unless said database owner is a superuser themselves, of course.

Reference: [PostgreSQL manual chapter on database roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/user-manag.html)